# MVVM firebase user authentification

Tags: java, android, firebase, mvvm, firebase-authentication

Since I am new to MVVM and Firebase, I tried creating a simple app, that signs up a User. The SignUp worked, but a weird error and crash of the application came with it. Since I am also trying to understand MVVM, I would appreciate tipps for better code. Anything that makes this better helps. Thanks

MainActivity

```
package com.example.testingapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    MainViewmodel model;
    EditText editEmail;
    EditText editPassword;
    Button btnSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editEmail = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        editPassword = findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewmodel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        model.email = editEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        model.password = editPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        model.signUp();
    }
}
```

MainViewmodel

```
package com.example.testingapp;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class MainViewmodel extends ViewModel {

    repo repository;
    String email;
    String password;

    public MainViewmodel(){
        if(repository == null){
            repository = new repo();
        }
    }

    public void signUp(){
        repository.firebaseSignUp(email, password);
    }
}
```

Repo

```
package com.example.testingapp;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class repo {

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    public void firebaseSignUp(String email, String password){
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseSignUp: Success" + email + password);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    }
                });


    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the crash log.

Comment: If you are interested in a Firebase authentication using MVVM, you can check this article: [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `(Executor) this,`. for me it is work.